# When I export a layer with a definition query, it does not maintain coverage. Why is that and how can I find a way to make it do that?

Tags: export, select-by-attribute, definition-query

I am trying to use the NHD waterbody layer in my map. As is, it is a really dense dataset, so I am narrowing it down to only show lakes (Ftype = 390). When I use the definition query, everything looks fine, both in the map viewer and in the layout view. When I export the layout, it appears that suddenly the waterbody coverage expands. It doesn't expand to the full NHD coverage, so clearly some filtering is being maintained through the export, but I'm not sure what is causing this change?

I tried using Select by Attribute (Ftype = 390) and that result seems to match the expanded coverage that results from exporting. To be honest, this is still too dense and distracts from the other data. I like the way it looks when I use the definition query. So two questions:Wwhy are the definition query and select by attribute tools spitting out two different results when the expression is the same? Also, how can I save the result from the definition query?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Definition queries can be saved in the project file. .aprx   Alternatively use the Select tool to output the results to a new dataset.